# Can a druid using wild shape and Natural Spell be counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I have a level 9 human druid with the Natural Spell feat selected. Since I live most of the time in animal shape, I would like to know:

- Is another caster able to counterspell me while I'm in natural shape?
- If the answer to previous question is no: considering the description of the Natural Spell feat, a bear will cast the same spell in different manner than a snake or a lion, what happens if a druid does not know a particular animal, can he counterspell? For example: two druids are fighting, the first comes from the Savannah, the second from icy north. The first get transformed into a rhino and starts to cast: is the latter able to understand what the rhino is launching?

Comment: Didn't wish to edit without making sure - but should the second point start with "If the answer to previous question is **yes**"? If a caster can't counterspell a spell cast by an animal, the second point is moot anyway...

Comment: No, if you answer no to the first, the second does not have any sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The rules are obviously unambiguous here. It sounds an awful lot like the real question here is the one of how the answer makes sense from a simulationist POV...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is another caster able to counterspell me while I'm in natural shape?

Yes. The [counterspell rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm) make no mention that the target must be in a recognisable form or anything like that. I can counterspell a human, I can counterspell a demon and I can counterspell a human who happens to be in the form of a lion, a bear or whatever else.

Comment: Well, This is what I knew and probably the right answer, but honestly I'm not convinced yet: If I have to take a feat to change verbal and somatic parts of a spell because I have no muscles or arms to do it in regular way (Natural Spell feat description), how someone else should know what I'm casting without a feat, a harder dc or a deep knowledge of that animal?

Comment: Because the [tag:rules-as-written] don't say that you need a feat, a harder DC or a deep knowledge of the animal. If you / your DM want to house-rule it, that's up to you.

Comment: That's it. Does te question have any sense anyway?

Comment: That sort of discussion would be much better in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

Comment: @IssamTP Yup, it's a houserule. I personally rule that using still spell, silent spell, natural spell, or other similar feats increase the spellcraft DC. Then again, we don't stick too closely to RAW. Your DM might rule it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Wild shape itself is listed as a supernatural ability and Supernatural abilities are magical and go away in an antimagic field but are not subject to spell resistance, counterspells, or to being dispelled by dispel magic. While casting spells in wild shape using natural spell, the same mechanics of normal spell casting apply, and an opposing caster may counter the spell if the dice are in his or her favor to identify the spell and counter it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of *Spellcraft* in counterspelling is written under the Skills section.

> Identify a spell being cast. (You must see or hear the spell's verbal or somatic components.) No action required. No retry.

So, no matter how the verbal or somatic components are altered, as long as at least one of them has been observed by the spellcaster, that spellcaster can make the check and try to counter this spell.

This is reasonable since the same spellcaster, even if the only language they knows is Common, can counter a spell being cast by a dragon (who is using verbal component in Draconic and doing somatic component with its claws) without an issue.

I believe it is for simplifying the game mechanism. Otherwise, every spellcaster would need to have a permanent *Tongue* on them, or they will have a very difficult time countering others' spells. (It is also worth mentioning that some languages in-game cannot be translated by the *Tongue* spell.)